# Precision measurements on sodium doublet wavelength?

Tags: specific-reference, spectroscopy

I'm currently searching for a good and reliable source where precision measurements on the wavelength of the so called sodium doublet ($D_1$ and $D_2$ lines) at approximately 589.0 nm and 589.6 nm are made.

Comment: You must know whether the wavelengths are in air or vacuum.  The frequency does not change with refractive index.

Comment: Minor point concerning retagging: I would say that the [tag:specific-reference] tag does not apply here cf. its [tag wiki](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [NIST Spectral Database](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/lines_form.html), entering sodium (Na) with $\lambda$ between 588nm and 590nm gives wavelengths of 588.9950954nm and 589.5924237nm.